# How to propagate update to child (using mobx and flutter)

Tags: flutter, mobile, mobx, observers, event-propagation

I am using mobx and flutter. I have an observable mobx map, and I want to update certain elements of the UI when a value in this map changes. I have the following code:

```
Observer(
        builder: (_) =>
          Column(
              children:[
               Text(widget.store.userVotes[key_name].toString()),#this works

               (widget.store.userVotes.containsKey(widget.doc.documentID))?
               YesNoSlider(
                 data: Metric("","",widget.store.userVotes[key_name])): #this doesn't work
                 SizedBox(height: 5),
              ]
          )
)
```

My problem is that the line with the comment "this works" updates correctly, but the child widget YesNoSlider does not. Even when the value of **widget.store.userVotes[key_name]** changes, the change does not get propagated to the child widget. Is there a way to propagate this change, and/or to build a version of YesNoSlider which would be able for changes? Or does the value in YesNoSlider that I want to update have to listen to the mobx store directly? Is mobx the wrong way to go about this problem? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!